Fantasy movie from around 2000s about a man searching for a woman
I watched this as a child and wasn't to interested in the film whilst watching so my memory of it is partial. But what I can recall is a few specific details: I believe the protagonist was a man Orlando Bloom-ish. I don't think it was him when his hair was shoulder length or man bun.
He's searching for a woman and there's repeated near misses. In one particular instance, he visits a large home/estate to speak to a man (the homeowner, I think) for  help; and the woman whom the male lead is searching for is stuck working in a kitchen, but she is mute/can't speak and so she sees him through a barred window and foot level but can't alert him. Also I think the woman and several others on the estate were wearing these odd cone shaped hats, like two cat ears, but with more pointed bandages or wrapped fabrics around their heads.
The film probably came out in the '00s (before 2010) and was a fantasy film. I believe it was set in an alternate reality, but it wasn't widely unrealistic. There were human characters and an older theme to the film - the 1800's maybe. The scenery looked European (France maybe), but everyone spoke English (not sure about accents). Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated. This has been bugging me for years just want to know which film it was.

Can you clean up how this is written? It's very hard to follow and figure out what you're talking about.

I don't know what but something in your description reminds me of the actress Audrey Tautou

Do you mean a hennin?

My guess would be the Movie Inkheart from 2008.
The main protagonist (played by Brandon Frasier) can read people inside and out of books, 9 years ago he lost his wife in a book when doing this, and now is searching for her while reading himself through some books. Regarding the specific book, he moves through some scenarios, also a 1800 Century scenario is included. 
When he finally is in the right location/book, inside a castle, his wife sees him but cant contact him, she is muted because of some errors during reading by a second person with this skill, which stutters. There is a lot more of plot in the movie, but i concentrated on the scenes you described.
You can find more information about the wife here

At some point, Capricorn found himself a reader, Darius. But though Darius was a Silvertongue, his reading was faulty, and he stumbled as he read, resulting in many disfigurations in the servants Darius brought out for Capricorn. Resa returned back to her world six years prior to Dustfinger's re-approachment to Mo, but due to Darius' stumbles she lost her voice along the way. 

The wife wears the hat you describe:

